# "ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error" when connecting to MySQL through some networks, but not others

Tags: mysql, ssl

When I try to connect to a MySQL server instance via command line, I get the following error:

```
computer:~ mysql -u user -h db.dbsite.com -p
Enter password: 

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib
```

Another user with access tried to reproduce it on their end, but connected successfully. Likewise, I can connect on my own home network. The issue has so far only appeared on a public coffee shop WiFi network. I don't have a strong background in networking some I'm not sure what attributes of the network would cause this issue.

I connect successfully elsewhere, so that rules out some of the other issues on StackOverflow ([incorrect certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/353296/mysql-error-2026-hy000-ssl-connection-error?rq=1) for one, likewise many other issues are related to invalid server SSL config). Skipping ssl as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413031/mysql-error-2026-hy000-ssl-connection-error-error00000001lib0func0re) is not viable because of the security risk.

Other info:

OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix in this case, it was as simple as adding `--ssl-mode=required`. It's unclear to me why this argument is required in this case and not others.

Comment: The solution is good but it doesn't solve the issue, if you really need the ssl connection.   VERIFY_CA: Like REQUIRED, but additionally verify the server Certificate Authority (CA) certificate against the configured CA certificates. The connection attempt fails if no valid matching CA certificates are found.